# Limit results to defined place types in Google Maps implementation

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to display a map that limits nearby results to a category that I designate. I have code that allows for the user to complete their own search, but would like to modify so that the search is disabled and the category is predefined. Source: http://www.gurchet-rai.net/apps/places/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var loc;
    var map;
    var service;
    var infoWindow;
    var overlays = [];
    var resultList = [];
    var isMobile = $(window).width < 767;

    try {           
        if (typeof navigator.geolocation !== 'undefined') {     
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (
                function(position) {    
                    var coords = position.coords;

                    loc = new google.maps.LatLng(coords.latitude, coords.longitude);
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                        mapTypeControl: false,
                        center: loc,
                        zoom: 13
                    });  

                    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);                        
                    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();            
                },      
                function(error) {
                    if (error.code == 1) {              
                        $('#location-details').append('Please enable location tracking in your web browser');
                    } else if (error.code == 2) {
                        $('#location-details').append('Unable to determine location - please ensure location tracking is enabled in your browser');         

                    } else {
                        $('#location-details').append('Unable to determine location');
                    }
                },
                {enableHighAccuracy: true}
            );  
        } else {
            $('#location-details').append('Your browser does not support location tracking');
        }
    } catch (e) {   
        alert('An error has occured');
    }   

    function plotResultList(){
        var iterator = 0;                  
        for(var i = 0; i < resultList.length; i++){
            setTimeout(function(){
                var lat = resultList[iterator].geometry.location.Za;
                var lng = resultList[iterator].geometry.location.Ya;
                var name = resultList[iterator].name;
                var addr = resultList[iterator].formatted_address;
                var reference = resultList[iterator].reference;

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: resultList[iterator].geometry.location,
                    map: map,
                    title: name,
                    animation: isMobile? 'undefined' : google.maps.Animation.DROP
                });
                overlays.push(marker);

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infoWindow.close();
                    var request = {
                        reference: reference
                    };

                    service.getDetails(request, function(place, status){
                        var content = "<h6>" + name + "</h6>";
                        if(status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK){    
                            if(typeof place.rating !== 'undefined'){
                                var badgeType = '';
                                if (place.rating < 2){
                                    badgeType = 'badge-important';
                                } else if (place.rating >= 2 && place.rating <= 3){
                                    badgeType = 'badge-warning';
                                } else {
                                    badgeType = 'badge-success';
                                }
                                content += "<p><small>Rating: <span class='badge " + badgeType + "'>" + place.rating + "</span></small></p>"; 
                            }    

                            if(typeof place.formatted_address !== 'undefined'){
                                content += "<br><small>" + place.formatted_address + "</small>";
                            }

                            if(typeof place.formatted_phone_number !== 'undefined'){
                                content += "<br><small><a href='tel:" + place.formatted_phone_number + "'>" + place.formatted_phone_number + "</a></small>";                                 
                            }

                            if(typeof place.website !== 'undefined'){
                                content += "<br><small><a href='" + place.website + "'>website</a></small>";

                            }
                        }                            

                        infoWindow.setContent(content);
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);         
                    });
                });
                iterator++;
            }, isMobile? 0: (i * 75));
        }
    }

    $('#search').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var query = $('#query').val();
        var request = {
            location: map.getCenter(),
            radius: '5000',
            query: query            
        };

        service.textSearch(request, function(results, status, pagination){
            for(var i = 0; i < overlays.length; i++){                   
                overlays[i].setMap(null);
            }
            resultList.length = 0;
            overlays.length = 0;
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                resultList = resultList.concat(results);
                plotResultList();
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests), specifically in the `types` parameter. [Here](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) are described the allowed types.

Let's say you want to show airports based on user's search, your `request` will be:

```
var request = {
    location: map.getCenter(),
    radius: '5000',
    query: query,
    types: ['airport']
};
```

Comment: please share those as an answer then links as a reference.

Comment: I looked at both of those pages prior to posting the question, but don't understand the implementation in this context. I want to preclude the user from searching and pass the defined parameter to the results @César Costa.

Comment: @Shane08 I didn't understand what precisely do you want. Adding the property `type` in your `request` variable and passing a type string wouldn't solve what you want to do?

Comment: @César Costa, I don't know how to pass the type string.

Comment: @Shane08 I edited my answer giving an example, see if it fits to your sittuation.